# bashrc alias search and replace using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find

I frequently need to search and replace throughout my code base. I use sed:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

I would like to be able to just type

```
sr 's/foo/bar/g'
```

I tried to add this to my .bashrc:

```
function sr
{
    find . -type f -exec sed -i '$1' {} +
}
```

But when I try to run
    sr 's/foo/bar/g'

I get

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `%'
```

How can I fix the above?

Comment: you say alias in the title, but then define a function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
function sr()
{
    find . -type f -exec sed -i "$1" {} +
}
```